# Count number of rows until a value is reached

Tags: r, count, row

I am trying to count the number of rows until a value is reached.
Here's an example dataset:

```
trialtype <- c(1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
RT <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,950)
fakedata <- cbind(trialtype,RT)
```

What I would like to do is for every trialtype = 0, count the number of rows above it where trialtype = 1 until it hits the beginning of the column (for the first 0) or until it hits another 0 (for the rest of the 0s), and create a new vector that contains the number of rows.
So my fake result for this data set would be something that looks like

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4)
numones <- c(2,2,0,1)
fakeresults <- cbind(x,numones)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your final `cbind` does not work. What do you want when trialtype==1?

Comment: @lmo I would like to count the number of rows where trialtype==1, that appears before every trialtype == 0. So for my fake data, there are two trialtype == 1 before the first trialtype == 0. And for the second trialtype == 0, there are also two trialtype == 0. But for my third trialtype == 0, there is 0 trialtype == 1. And basically create another dataframe that keeps track of all this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the indexes of the zeroes using an equality comparison and [`which()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html). Then, compute [`diff()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diff.html) minus one on the index vector, with a prepended zero to provide the correct distance prior to the first index.

```
zis <- which(fakedata[,'trialtype']==0);
data.frame(x=seq_along(zis),numones=diff(c(0L,zis))-1L);
##   x numones
## 1 1       2
## 2 2       2
## 3 3       0
## 4 4       1
```

This will only work if there are only zeroes and ones in the input column. If there are other values, and you're interested only in counting *ones* prior to zeroes, then a more complex solution will be needed.